# Possible to run BizTalk 2006 and 2009 on same server?

Tags: installation, biztalk, biztalk-2009

Have you ever tried running instances of BizTalk 2006R2 and BizTalk 2009 on the same server?

If yes: were you able to do so without using virtualization?

Any feedback you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be done.  There are too many ways in which BizTalk assumes it's the only BizTalk instance on the machine.